# Conditional Sentences where it's not known whether the condition with if clause got fulfilled or not

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals

As far as my knowledge goes, the third conditional is used in cases where we're talking about a past condition for example

> If she had come home early , she would have got to meet him.

Well the person didn't get home early so she didn't get to see whoever she wanted to see.

But what about the cases where it's not certain whether the condition with '*if*' clause got fulfilled or not?

In the above sentence if it wasn't known whether she came home early or not. What should be used instead of ***If she had come early***? It clearly implies that she didn't come home early .

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Your ELU question has been closed and migrated here. And since this is a duplicate question, we have merged the two questions. You can follow [this link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/270325/how-to-handle-con-di-tional-clauses-where-it-s-un-known-whether-the-pro-ta-sis-s) to the merged question. Also it appears you have created two accounts. You can use your ELU account to access ELL too, in case you don't know. You can request your two accounts merged using [this form](https://ell.stackexchange.com/contact).