# How to handle con­di­tional clauses where it’s un­known whether the pro­ta­sis’s con­di­tion ac­tu­ally got ful­filled or not?

Tags: conditionals, modal-verbs, negation, sequence-of-tenses

I have a ques­tion re­gard­ing con­di­tional sen­tences, as far I know the “third con­di­tional” is used when we’re talk­ing about a con­di­tion from the past that never
ac­tu­ally hap­pened af­ter all.  For ex­am­ple:

- If she **had come** home early, she **would have got­ten
  to meet** him.

In this ex­am­ple, the per­son did not get home early so she
did not get to see whomever she had been want­ing to see.

But what about the cases where it’s un­cer­tain whether that *if* clause’s con­di­tion had ever ended up getting fulfilled or not?

If in the ex­am­ple sen­tence it had not been known whether
she had come home early — maybe she did, maybe she didn’t,
but we don’t know — what then would have been used in place
of *If she had come home early*, given how that par­tic­u­lar
con­struc­tion would clearly im­ply that she had not come
home early and we want to al­low for doubt about that?

Comment: "If she came home early, she will have got to meet him."

Comment: 'If she came / did come home early, she will have met him / got to meet him.'

Comment: The sentence is only grammatical in UK English. In American English it would be _gotten to meet him_. Otherwise it's grammatical, and appropriate no matter what the speaker knew; though nobody but your English teacher can tell you Which Number Conditional it is.

Comment: The *would* in "she would have got­ten to meet him" is needed only as part of the subjunctive tense.  When you remove the counterfactual sense, you don't get a non-subjunctive form of *would* (*will*), it completely goes away.  So **"If she came home early, she got to meet him."**

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The sentence is claiming the subject had the opportunity to meet someone, not that she did.  So "will have met him" is not quite the same.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Are you saying that 'If she came home early, she got to meet him' and 'If she came home early, she will have met him' have different meanings? The denoted meanings are 'If A, then B' in each case.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes those mean different things.  Getting to do something is not the same as doing it.  For example "Everyone with the premium tickets got to go backstage after the concert, but I chose to go home early,"

Comment: @Ben Voigt 'She will have met him' can have the pragmatic emphasis (Oh yes, she will) that 'she got to meet him' has. You're not considering the flexibility of the language. 'A means X'. Yes. And/or Y. Z ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I didn't say that is ungrammatical.  I said it is not the same sense.  "she got to meet him" does not express emphasis, it expresses potential and implies the potential is not equally available to everyone.  That implied exclusivity is not present in any form in "She will have met him".

Answer (score 2):

**If she had come home early she *might have* gotten to meet him.**

The 'might have' indicates that coming home late she definitely didn't get to meet him, but even coming home early it was only a possibility.